# MySQL, PHP - Count individual items in a single column

Tags: php, mysql

In a MySQL database I have the following data:

```
field     data
47        ABC
47        DEF
47        GHI
47        ABC
47        DEF
47        GHI
```

When I run the following query, it gives me what I want:

```
$myquery = mysqli_query($con,
"SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS Rows, data 
FROM my_table 
WHERE field = '47' 
GROUP BY data 
ORDER BY data");
```

The output is like this:

```
Rows     Data
1        ABC
3        DEF
17       GHI
```

There are roughly 500 unique combinations in `Data`

In PHP I then do a `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($myquery);` but it only returns the information for the first row.

How can I have PHP assign each combination as a variable (example: $ABC, $DEF, etc.)?  ... or, how can I otherwise extract the counts for each unique combination?

Comment: `but it only returns the information for the first row.`.... yes, you have to loop and fetch each row in turn

Comment: `How can I have PHP assign each combination as a variable`.... just don't.... you lose control of your variables that way, never knowing what they might be called; just use an array

Comment: That's actually working as documented. If you want the whole result set, you should either use a `while` loop, or `mysqli_fetch_all()` function.